# MAX funtion in SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I need to query a table to extract maximum values of purchases in any month. However, if there are 2 months with both having the maximum number of purchases, the query should return both. MAX function only returns one of them. How do I pull both or more if available

Comment: can you please provide some sample data?

Comment: `GROUP BY`? Check the documentation of your DBMS, section about aggregate functions. There should be a description. Or alternatively you can take some SQL tutorials, there're tons of them over the internet

Comment: MAX() doesn't return any of your months, it returns the maximum purchase value.

Answer (score 1):

You can `GROUP BY` by the month(Do not know the exact names of your columns so I wild guessed):

```
select max(purchases), month
from db.table
group by month
```

So you will have something like this(EXAMPLE DATA).

```
max(purchases)   month
   100           1
   200           2
   150           3
   150           4
```

etc.

Comment: Please marked it as an answer if it suits you.